# Image not displayed on html

Tags: html, image, src

Image is not displayed on the bootstrap carousel template while trying to load it locally.The image loads when the absolute url (online link) is mentioned. I can't see what mistake I might have made.

The folder tree is included in the picture.

I have tried using absolute image links i.e. online links and the code works perfectly.

While trying to insert the pictures locally, I have tried using \ instead of / , renaming the image files and putting the files in different folders .

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
This is the block title.
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
</div class='container'>
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="cartoon.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="rick_morty.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="rick_morty.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: We can't really help with image path problems. Look in your browser's console for errors. Check what path is rendered in the document. Unless the images are in the same folder as your HTML source _in the compiled application on the server_ what you have here won't work. The internet is chock full of tutorials on relative paths. Also, this isn't a Bootstrap question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the image's `src` tag is always starting with `/`, and the images are in the main path of the site, for example: `example.com/cartoon.jpg`.

So, your images would look something like this:

```html
<img src="/rick_morty.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

and the image must be available under `yoursiteurl/rick_morty.jpg`